# Google Sheets Lookup a value in cells that contains a range itself

Tags: google-sheets

I am struggling to find a way to solve the problem below.

I have two columns in Google Sheets, like the image below:

[image]

I want to lookup a value, eg. 35 in the right column (B3:B21) and take as result the value in column A (A3:A21).

This value (35) is between 34-36, thus the lookup should return 15.

I don't want to change the columns at all. I want to find the solutions leaving the columns as they are.

The solution should use only existing formulas, not custom through script.
I have created a script to give me the result, but I don't prefer this method.

Could anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=xlookup(35,index(--regexextract(B:B,"\d+")),A:A,,-1)
```

Comment: I am impressed! It works. I don't understand exactly how.... but it works! Thank you very much!